# Combine list of items into a single bucket with a certain value, then create pie chart

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to create a pie chart with four levels of risk from high to low risk. I have a list of items that I will manually assign a risk level. I then need to group those representing a single level creating four different level groups. These I will need to graph using a pie chart. How do I do this?

Comment: Will there be four concentric rings to this chart representing the levels with each level being subdivided, or will there be a pie chart with four wedges that have lists of items attached to them?

Comment: The latter - a pie with four wedges demonstrating the totals for each group, i.e. low risk comprises of 5 items averaging 40% of the total pie, high risk comprising of 3 items averaging 30%, and so on.

Comment: By totals do you mean a count of items in each group?

Comment: yes - say, 20 items, where 4 of them fall in the High risk category, 6 in the medium category, 6 in the medium, 4 in the low. So the formula would calculate the percentage for each group in the pie.

Comment: Did you get my response Jason?

Answer (score 1):

Before creating the pie chart, you should perform the calculation of the information that will go into the chart.

Here's an example:
[image]

The `A` column holds the data, and the `D` column holds the results of the formula. `C` is just there to be a little more clear of what you're seeing.

In this example, if we want to get the percentage of `1`s in column `A`, the formula would be `=(COUNTIF(A:A, "=1")/COUNT(A:A))`, where `"=1"` gets replaced with whatever you are searching for. In `D1`, it's `"=1"`, in `D2` it's `"=2"`, and so on.

Once you have this information calculated correctly, creating a pie chart will be as easy as adding the chart and selecting the four `D` rows (in this example).